# Библиотека под лицензией WTFPL. Нужно ли указывать текст лицензии?

Tags: android, лицензирование

Здравствуйте. Использую вот эту библиотеку в android приложении: https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

Она находится по лицензией

> "DO WHAT THE FUCK YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE"

Нужно ли в окне `"О программе"` указывать этот текст лицензии и автора?
 Или эта лицензия предполагает использование библиотеки без упоминания об авторе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, необходимо, если планируете распространять программу в [странах, принявших Бернскую конвенцию](http://licenseit.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (среди которых есть РФ и США).

1. Упоминание авторства — это реализация *права на авторство*, относящегося к неисключительным правам.
2. Упоминание лицензии — указание на условия, по которым вам была передана копия библиотеки. Дело в том, что ничто не мешает автору раздавать одну и ту же библиотеку под различными лицензиями различным людям и предприятиям.

   Соответственно, при дальнейшем распространении (если лицензия это разрешает) вы мало того что тоже должны предоставить пользователям условия и разрешения, так ещё и указать, что это самое распространение вообще законно.