# Авторские права на GitHub?

Tags: битрикс, github, cms, лицензирование, авторские-права

Не пойму какое реальное практическое применение имеет сервис github и как обстоят дела с авторскими правами?

1. В чем логика выкладывать свой код на всеобщее обозрение, чтобы
   его скопировали и потом продавали? Или там реальные вещи, которые
   несут материальную ценность не выкладываются? Или там что-то типа: о
   посмотрите, я написал новый супер-аудиоплеер, качайте на здоровье и
   пользуйтесь. Или сервис наполовину коммерческий, типа вот
   ограниченные версии кода, можете пользоваться, а если хотите что-то
   нормальное - покупайте лицензию?
2. И что понимается под авторскими правами на GitHub-e, да и вообще
   впринципе. Верстка сайта (сами блоки, расположение), если
   скопировать (кроме дизайна) - это считается нарушением авторских
   прав? С дизайном понятно, если макет один в один - это вроде как
   нарушение авторских прав. И кстати, сам дизайн макет по сути
   налеплен из разных фоток, зачастую с лицами людей - сами-то
   дизайнеры откуда берут это все, тупо качают из интернета чужие
   фотки?
3. Если взять код с функционалом типа CMS - это тоже нарушение
   авторских прав? Может я что-то не понимаю, но принцип CMS же
   примерно одинаковый, генерить статичные страницы, каталог и прочее
   взаимодействие? Взять тот же Bitrix, это что-то супер-уникальное
   чего нет в открытом доступе? Неужели за столько лет развития
   интернета в сети не появилось бесплатного качественного аналога
   платной CMS?

Comment: 1) Мне нравится делиться с людьми, я не жадный до денег. Кстати, можно лицензией запретить продавать (а с кодом без указанной лицензии делать вообще ничего нельзя по законам всех стран); 2) Что такое авторские права и на что они распространяются — читайте в законах США и страны вашего проживания, гитхаб тут ни при чём; 3) То же самое, это всё регулируется законами, а не гитхабом

Comment: Для описания прав на код используется файл LICENSE, в котором указывает лицензия / лицензии для использования. Если вас так беспокоит коммерческое использование, просто распространяете код бесплатно под лицензией, запрещающей коммерческое использование, а продавайте с другой лицензией (коммерческой).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> В чем логика выкладывать свой код на всеобщее обозрение, чтобы его скопировали и потом продавали?

1. Есть такое понятие, как свободное ПО. Это когда вы выкладываете свой код под свободной лицензией, а в ответ получаете сообщество (по сути, бесплатных программистов, тестировщиков, авторов документации и многопрофильную службу поддержки на добровольных началах, мотивированных исключительно интересом к вашему продукту).
2. Этот подход, кстати, применим и в бизнесе. В этом случае разработчик зарабатывает за счёт продажи не самого продукта (платформы), а своего рода премиум-услуг к нему (дополнительные модули, расширенная поддержка, помощь в интеграции и т. д.). В этом случае копирование кода не принесёт какого-либо вреда — всё равно дохода непосредственно от него ноль.
3. Также компании могут выкладывать свои старые разработки, которые потеряли коммерческую ценность.

> Или там реальные вещи, которые несут материальную ценность не выкладываются?

Вот вам пара примеров продуктов, живущих и здравствующих с такой бизнес-моделью:

- NGINX (некоммерческая версия: https://nginx.ru/ru/ и коммерческая версия: https://www.nginx.com/),
- Qt (https://www.qt.io/).

Эти вещи реальны и приносят доход своим компаниям-владельцам.

Насчёт web-фреймворков сказать ничего не могу — не моя область.

> Или сервис наполовину коммерческий, типа вот ограниченные версии кода, можете пользоваться, а если хотите что-то нормальное — покупайте лицензию?

Исходные коды продукта выложены в репозиторий, поэтому ни о какой пробной версии речи идти не может.

> И что понимается под авторскими правами на GitHub-e, да и вообще в принципе.

То, что прописано в местных законах об авторском праве. Процитирую свой [старый ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/718211/208074) на смежную тему:

> ... если планируете распространять программу в [странах, принявших Бернскую конвенцию](http://licenseit.ru/wiki/index.php/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1_%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B8_%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (среди которых есть РФ и США).
>
> 1. Упоминание авторства — это реализация *права на авторство*, относящегося к неисключительным правам.
> 2. Упоминание лицензии — указание на условия, по которым вам была передана копия библиотеки. Дело в том, что ничто не мешает автору раздавать одну и ту же библиотеку под различными лицензиями различным людям и предприятиям.
>
> Соответственно, при дальнейшем распространении (если лицензия это разрешает) вы мало того что тоже должны предоставить пользователям условия и разрешения, так ещё и указать, что это самое распространение вообще законно.

---

> Верстка сайта (сами блоки, расположение), если скопировать (кроме дизайна) — это считается нарушением авторских прав? С дизайном понятно, если макет один в один — это вроде как нарушение авторских прав.

Тут весьма тонкая грань — надо обращаться к юристу.

> И кстати, сам дизайн макет по сути налеплен из разных фоток, зачастую с лицами людей — сами-то дизайнеры откуда берут это все, тупо качают из интернета чужие фотки?

Кстати да, покупая макет, вы имеете право запросить копии всех лицензионных соглашений дизайнера этого макета с авторами фотографий или фотобанками.

> Если взять код с функционалом типа CMS — это тоже нарушение авторских прав?

Зависит от лицензии (лицензионного соглашения), под которой этот код распространялся. Если она это разрешает, то нет, не является.

> Может я что-то не понимаю, но принцип CMS же примерно одинаковый, генерить статичные страницы, каталог и прочее взаимодействие? Взять тот же Bitrix, это что-то супер-уникальное чего нет в открытом доступе? Неужели за столько лет развития интернета в сети не появилось бесплатного качественного аналога платной CMS?

С одной стороны, эту генерацию можно производить по разному. Но, с другой стороны, имеется [нехороший прецедент судебной тяжбы между Oracle и Google из-за девяти строк кода](http://www.cnews.ru/news/top/google_nakazali_za_9_strok_koda_oracle). Так что с этим, опять же, только к юристу.